# I can't install Gevent

Tags: python, python-2.7, gevent

I need to install Gevent for python2.7 but after try almost all I still doesn't install it.
I have python 2.6.6 and here all work ok... but I need python2.7+ then I install python 2.7.9 and now have only problems...
Before some part of my project work in python 2.6 ok, but now my project doesn't run witn 2.6 and 2.7, dunno why it's stop working with 2.6 but nvm I need it with 2.7 but.... I cant instal gevent, I have installed libevent-devel an greenlet but I can't instal gevent

```sh
# pip2.7 install gevent
Collecting gevent
  Using cached gevent-1.0.1.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): greenlet in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from gevent)
Installing collected packages: gevent
  Running setup.py install for gevent
    configure: error: in `/tmp/pip-build-fpnLvN/gevent/build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libev':
    configure: error: cannot run C compiled programs.
    If you meant to cross compile, use `--host'.
    See `config.log' for more details
    Running '/bin/sh /tmp/pip-build-fpnLvN/gevent/libev/configure > configure-output.txt' in /tmp/pip-build-fpnLvN/gevent/build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libev
    building 'gevent.core' extension
    ccache gcc -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DLIBEV_EMBED=1 -DEV_COMMON= -DEV_CLEANUP_ENABLE=0 -DEV_EMBED_ENABLE=0 -DEV_PERIODIC_ENABLE=0 -Ibuild/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libev -Ilibev -I/usr/local/include/python2.7 -c gevent/gevent.core.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/gevent/gevent.core.o
    In file included from gevent/libev.h:2,
                     from gevent/gevent.core.c:313:
    libev/ev.c:45:22: error: config.h: No such file or directory
    libev/ev.c:477:48: warning: "/*" within comment
    In file included from gevent/libev.h:2,
                     from gevent/gevent.core.c:313:
    libev/ev.c:1531: warning: ‘ev_default_loop_ptr’ initialized and declared ‘extern’
    In file included from gevent/libev.h:2,
                     from gevent/gevent.core.c:313:
    libev/ev.c: In function ‘ev_io_start’:
    libev/ev.c:3554: warning: suggest parentheses around arithmetic in operand of ‘|’
    libev/ev.c:4795:27: warning: "/*" within comment
    libev/ev.c:4796:27: warning: "/*" within comment
    error: command 'ccache' failed with exit status 1
    Complete output from command /usr/local/bin/python2.7 -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-fpnLvN/gevent/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-Ruy7Xb-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install

    running build

    running build_py

    creating build

    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7

    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/gevent

    copying gevent/resolver_thread.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/gevent

    copying gevent/socket.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/gevent

    copying gevent/threadpool.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/gevent

    copying gevent/util.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/gevent

    copying gevent/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/gevent

    copying gevent/monkey.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/gevent

    copying gevent/queue.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/gevent

    copying gevent/coros.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/gevent

    copying gevent/server.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/gevent

    copying gevent/_threading.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/gevent

    copying gevent/thread.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/gevent

    copying gevent/select.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/gevent

    copying gevent/hub.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/gevent

    copying gevent/fileobject.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/gevent

    copying gevent/wsgi.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/gevent

    copying gevent/pywsgi.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/gevent

    copying gevent/event.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/gevent

    copying gevent/greenlet.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/gevent

    copying gevent/ssl.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/gevent

    copying gevent/local.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/gevent

    copying gevent/subprocess.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/gevent

    copying gevent/threading.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/gevent

    copying gevent/os.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/gevent

    copying gevent/win32util.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/gevent

    copying gevent/baseserver.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/gevent

    copying gevent/lock.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/gevent

    copying gevent/backdoor.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/gevent

    copying gevent/pool.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/gevent

    copying gevent/resolver_ares.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/gevent

    copying gevent/timeout.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/gevent

    running build_ext

    configure: error: in `/tmp/pip-build-fpnLvN/gevent/build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libev':

    configure: error: cannot run C compiled programs.

    If you meant to cross compile, use `--host'.

    See `config.log' for more details

    Running '/bin/sh /tmp/pip-build-fpnLvN/gevent/libev/configure > configure-output.txt' in /tmp/pip-build-fpnLvN/gevent/build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libev

    building 'gevent.core' extension

    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/gevent

    ccache gcc -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DLIBEV_EMBED=1 -DEV_COMMON= -DEV_CLEANUP_ENABLE=0 -DEV_EMBED_ENABLE=0 -DEV_PERIODIC_ENABLE=0 -Ibuild/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libev -Ilibev -I/usr/local/include/python2.7 -c gevent/gevent.core.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/gevent/gevent.core.o

    In file included from gevent/libev.h:2,

                     from gevent/gevent.core.c:313:

    libev/ev.c:45:22: error: config.h: No such file or directory

    libev/ev.c:477:48: warning: "/*" within comment

    In file included from gevent/libev.h:2,

                     from gevent/gevent.core.c:313:

    libev/ev.c:1531: warning: ‘ev_default_loop_ptr’ initialized and declared ‘extern’

    In file included from gevent/libev.h:2,

                     from gevent/gevent.core.c:313:

    libev/ev.c: In function ‘ev_io_start’:

    libev/ev.c:3554: warning: suggest parentheses around arithmetic in operand of ‘|’

    libev/ev.c:4795:27: warning: "/*" within comment

    libev/ev.c:4796:27: warning: "/*" within comment

    error: command 'ccache' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
    Command "/usr/local/bin/python2.7 -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-fpnLvN/gevent/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-Ruy7Xb-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-fpnLvN/gevent
```

Comment: It looks like you're using `ccache`. Try *not* using `ccache` but just plain `cc`...This is probably your problem. If it's not, share your `config.log` (using `cc`, not `ccache`).

Comment: @Carpetsmoker how can I do this?

Comment: My python config.log - > 37.233.101.14/config.log

Comment: Well, `ccache` is something you or someone enabled manually. You're probably setting the `CC` environment variable in some shell startup script somewhere ... You can try running setting the `CC` to `gcc` before running `pip install` like so: `env CC=gcc pip install gevent `

Comment: I give try to gcc but it doesn't help [link](http://pastebin.com/wvb0tkub)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is solution for my problem [enter link description here](https://my.bluehost.com/cgi/help/530)

Probably this is most important (in place of `python2.X` type your python ver. eg. `python2.7`)
`export PYTHONPATH=$HOME/.local/lib/python/site-packages:$PYTHONPATH`
`export PYTHONPATH=$HOME/.local/lib/python2.X/site-packages:$PYTHONPATH`
`export PATH=$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH`

Comment: The link no longer works...

Answer (score 23):

Installing this worked for me,

```
sudo apt-get install libevent-dev
sudo apt-get install python-all-dev
```

and then,

```
pip install greenlet
pip install gevent
```

Comment: two hours googling around and found this... working ! +1

Comment: i am able to install gevent but can't be found in virtual env.

Answer (score 3):

It worked for me. First remove gevent from Pipfile.lock

```
"gevent": {
        "hashes": [
            "sha256:004cdbc6c18b4076acfa256c1794abf87bf9b97e0cfd4136f5098535c4b4132e",
            "sha256:3ae1ca0f533ddcb17aab16ce66b424b3f3b855ff3b9508526915d3c6b73fba31",
            "sha256:704a048005e6389fcb8276113bb9e7d0a3160bc382b9bcc629e398a43645de5c",
            "sha256:80ee22c28dae6dc70c7e4385f0d0292da9eebccf14b90620a32f10d71797838e",
            "sha256:aa224957cbbc028bbdfbec89625c7efa66bb8ddb845ed2fe323bd6b24e919dcf",
            "sha256:f3e8656f0b7bce355f14896d0b644c0a91e01fa12d9d65e6b09faad1d2c06e65"
        ],
        "index": "pypi",
        "version": "==1.0.2"
}
```

Then install gevent manually `pipenv install gevent`

Hope it will work for you.

Answer (score 3):

Had a similar issue, upgrading pip with

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

worked for me. Make sure you have the latest version. In my case, I assumed making a new virtual environment automatically provides the latest version but I was wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve this same issue on my raspberry pi zero by using a compiled binary instead of pip.

`sudo apt-get install python-gevent`

Answer (score 0):

Besides:
    sudo apt-get install libevent-dev
    sudo apt-get install python-all-dev

I also need to install (I used python3) to solve similar issue
    **sudo apt-get install python3-dev**

Answer (score 0):

I tried installing a bunch of other packages as described by some of the other answers, so not sure if any of those helped, but the thing that got it working in the end was using `easy_install` rather than `pip`:

```
easy_install gevent
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting errors trying to install gevent-websocket 0.10.1 however the problem was solved when I installed greenlet:

```
pip3 install greenlet
```

first and then:

```
pip3 install gevent-websocket
```